# Paypal The response from IPN was: INVALID

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Im trying to sell in my website, and i'm new in paypal, i have read many tutorials and documentations but steel no result.
So I have created Buy now button, as i understand in the past there was button with many of hidden inputs that have value of payment redirecting url ect. , but now when im creating button its just give button id .. here is it 
`<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="JGPBAD3STWN6Q" />
<input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" />
<img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/ru_RU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</form>`

The price and redirection urls i filled while creating button.

And this is my ipn code

```
<?php 
// STEP 1: read POST data
// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set 
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // The IPN is verified, process it:
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process the notification
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
    // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
    echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
}
?>
```

So when im trying to buy my product the transaction seems to all right but when redirecting to my website code print The response from IPN was: INVALID

Is there someone who can help with this ? 
Thanks Advanced

Answer (score 1):

In the form action, you are directing to **https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr**

But In the IPN code your

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
```

So one points to the sandbox, but not the other. That should be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your IPN handler, not in this code. It should be obvious that this code must work, otherwise no IPN would have happened at all. You need to post the *relevant* code. Probably you haven't built the validation callback URL correctly, or you aren't sending it to the right URL (sandbox or live).

Comment: Hi, i added my IPN code and as you can see the url contains sandbox and i use sandbox button and buyer account

Comment: You don't need to use the parsed post data in the verify request. Just add the raw post data to $req. PayPal also state that using the same order is significant, although as I do this in Java where using the same order isn't even possible, I don't actually believe it.

Comment: Sorry but i cant understand how to post data to $req

Comment: EJP I have tested mi IPN in developers testing tools and all right with ipn but there are no posts from paypal, i just have no post to ann them in $req , whi ? what could it be ?

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you don't understand. You have the raw post data in your code, in a variable named exactly that.

Comment: could you please post an example with normal post data ?